# How do I copy Postgres tables from one DB to another in a memory-efficient way?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to build an application in Python that copies a large series of tables from one database (or a set of databases) to another singular database.

I am using Psycopg2 for this purpose, and for smaller tables, my existing code works nicely. I simply fetch the table, store it in a Pandas DataFrame, then copy it into the target database using the `copy_expert` function:

```
    df.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=True, index=False)
    output.seek(0)
    copy_query = "COPY " + table + " FROM STDOUT csv DELIMITER '\t' NULL ''  ESCAPE '\\' HEADER "
    cur.copy_expert(copy_query, output)
```

Again, this works for small tables, but for large tables with tens of columns and millions of rows, I burn through tons of memory (which results in crashes) and often have my copy requests cancelled by the remote DB (whos config I cannot adjust to remedy that issue, likely due to time-outs).

Is there a more memory-efficient way I can copy a large number of very-big tables using Psycopg2?

Please note that I am also trying to implement my copy solution in the form of a "consumer" using the multi-threaded ["producer-consumer" pattern](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/producer-consumer.html).

Thank you for your help and advice!

Comment: The remote db doesn't know or care how much memory your local python process uses.  What reason does it give for cancelling?

Comment: It doesn't give a reason. It just cancels the copy. My assumption is that it is a time-out issue.